# How to control checkBox's checked props?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I made checkbox component and inside, 
set `isChecked` state to remember checked values even after re-render in case of 
new data will be fetched. 
but because of this, `isChecked` state makes every checkbox being checked.
here is example. https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-sun-pm8o9?file=/src/App.js

 how can I control checkboxes individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've only a single `isChecked` value to toggle all the checkboxes.

## A Solution - There are multiple

1. Store an array of checked booleans. Initialize the state to an array computed from the `items` prop.

   ```
   const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(items.map((_) => false));
   ```
2. Update `check` onChange handler to also consume an index value. Note here that I've also rewritten this handler as a curried function that consumes the `item` and `index` and returns the callback function that takes the `onChange` event object. Use the `index` to map the previous state to the next state, saving the `checked` value when the index matches.

   ```
   const check = (item, index) => (e) => {
     const { checked } = e.target;
     handleCheck(checked, item);
     setIsChecked((isChecked) =>
       isChecked.map((el, i) => (i === index ? checked : el))
     );
   };
   ```
3. When mapping the `items` prop to the checkbox inputs, use the index to pass to the `onChange` handler and to access the `isChecked` checked value.

   ```
   return items.map((item, i) => (
     <FormControlLabel
       value="start"
       control={
         <Checkbox
           ...
           onChange={check(item, i)} // <-- pass item and index i
           checked={isChecked[i]}    // <-- get checked value from state by index i
         />
       }
       label={item}
       labelPlacement="end"
     />
   ));
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-control-checkboxs-checked-props]